# why my validation is not working? asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller

I tried to put a `ValidationMessageFor` in my view to control data but it's not working and data goes to my post action.

Here is my model class:

```
 public enum CustomerType
    {
        JuridicalPerson,
        NaturalPerson
    }
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("ID")]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your first name")]
        [DisplayName("First name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter your last name")]
        [DisplayName("Last name")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please choose your customer type")]
        [DisplayName("Customer type")]
        public CustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
```

and here is my create customer view:

```
@model Contracts.Models.Customer

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="box">
        <div class="input-container">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="input-container">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
            <br />
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="input-container">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerType)
            <br />
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerType, "Select a type", new {@class ="input-container" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerType)
        </div>
        <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Create" />
    </div>
}
```

and finally this is my customer controller and its action for create a customer:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Customer customer)
        {
//db is my database context
            db.Customers.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

actually with html helper validation in my view ,empty inputs should give an error and not goes to my action but is's not working

I'll appreciate if you help me

Comment: Are you using client side validation scripts such as unobstrusive jquery? Is it injected in your view via Layout page or something?

Comment: sorry I am beginner. No I didn't use any scripts except one scripts.render that I added in my layout page for add css in my views.
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
if (ModelState.IsValid){
        db.Customers.Add(customer);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");} return Page();
```